# jQuery.ajax adding '(MISSING)' to JSON response when passing '%' (perc symbol)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm puzzled by this:
test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    console.log(jQuery.parseJSON('{"key" : "value_%"}'));  ## line 10
    $.ajax(
    { url : "/scripts/test.pl",
      success : function(resp) {console.log(resp); console.log(jQuery.parseJSON(resp))}
    }
    );
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

/scripts/test.pl:

```
print '{"key":"value_%"}';
```

Output:

```
Object {key: "value_%"} test.html:10
{"key":"value_%"(MISSING)} test.html:13
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( jquery.min.js:3
```

i.e. The ajax response is changing the JSON text adding this '(MISSING)' bit and thus making parseJSON to fail.

Why is this happening? and how should I avoid that?

M;

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to manually call parseJSON. Just use the dataType option

```
$.ajax({ 
  url : "/scripts/test.pl",
  dataType: "json",
  success : function(resp) {console.log(resp);}
  } );
```

Comment: I am calling parseJSON manually to debug the problem. If I set the dataType, the success callback is never fired and I get a "parsererror" instead. Anyway, the problem is the insertion of the "(MISSING)" bit by $.ajax, not how I am parsing the JSON.

Comment: Have you checked the response of the network call in debugging tools? It may be your server is inserting this and could be the one at fault. This seems far more likely than the jquery ajax function being at fault.

Comment: Yep, you hit the nail. It is the server trying to interpret the '%' in the value (I am echoing the script response in a kind of printf). Thanks for the help!